# Cant connect to workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Im trying to complete the very first training module offered by MS. Something Im missing that isn't detailed on the documentation of the training.

These are the instructions I'm following
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-aml-labs/blob/master/labdocs/Lab01.md

All good until I have to run the second command defined on the notebook called 
"01-Getting_Started_with_Azure_ML.ipynb". 
And yes I entered the device login code as the instructions indicate.

Look at the attached screenshot of the error returned after running the command of the notebook.

[image: Scheenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Opened a case with Microsoft. They noticed is an issue affecting their VM servers.

This is their reply:

> Hi Marbin,
>
> Hope you are doing good. I had discussed this with our team as well. This was a known issue with workspace names with capital letters. So, the workspace name ‘ML_Battlefield’ was creating the issue. This is fixed in SDK version 1.3.0.
>
> In the compute instance notebook, we can update the SDK version to:  pip install --upgrade azureml-sdke